# terraform kubernetes_storage_class for azurefile on aks

Tags: azure, kubernetes, terraform, azure-aks

I am converting some kubernetes yaml files to terraform.  I have got almost everything working but I am stuck with my storageClass.  I need to use azurefile and I can not work out how to set the file permissions for the mount.

As far as I can tell this is the supported syntax:

```
resource "kubernetes_storage_class" "azurefile" {
  metadata {
    name = "azurefile"
  }
  storage_provisioner = "kubernetes.io/azure-file"
  reclaim_policy = "Retain"
  parameters {
    skuName = "Standard_LRS"
  }
}
```

However I don't know where I can specify mount options.

Here is the yaml I am starting with:

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: azurefile
provisioner: kubernetes.io/azure-file
mountOptions:
  - dir_mode=0777
  - file_mode=0777
  - uid=1000
  - gid=1000
parameters:
  skuName: Standard_LRS
```

Is there any supported way to add in the mount options?  If not, I will not be able to use azure file. Has anyone been able to do this and if not, do you have a work-around?

I know I can use local_exec (I had already done this) but that is what I am trying to move away from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to update the thread, mount_options are now available in the latest versions of terraform (as of Feb 2020). [terraform_provider_kubernetes v1.11.0](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-kubernetes/releases/tag/v1.11.0) and up have the mount_options available.

```
resource "kubernetes_storage_class" "azurefile" {
  metadata {
    name = "azurefile"
  }
  storage_provisioner = "kubernetes.io/azure-file"
  reclaim_policy = "Retain"
  parameters {
    skuName = "Standard_LRS"
  }
  mount_options = ["file_mode=0777", "dir_mode=0777", "uid=1000", "gid=1000"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yeah, looking at [this](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/kubernetes/r/storage_class.html) it doesn't seem like mountOptions are supported in terraform yet.

Comment: Do you have any ideas?  Is there another way to do this?  azuredisk does not support readwritemany, so I need this.

Comment: that's the pvc property, not storageclass. also, what does it have to do with azuredisk if the question is about azurefiles?

Comment: sorry.  Meant azurefiles.  If you don't set the permissions on the storage class dynamic provisioning won't work.  unless there is another way to set the values used for dynamic provisioning I don't know about.  I started with this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-files-dynamic-pv